# What I am doing wrong with twitter API?

Tags: wordpress, api, twitter, widget

I am making a widget using https://github.com/j7mbo/twitter-api-php.

My widget is working fine there is no problem in my widget.

**So what's the problem:**

Inside my `TwitterWidget` Class whichi is extending `WP_Widget` inside the `widget( $args, $instance )`. I have make a function inside :

Here is it:

```
function get_Connection_With_Twitter_API( $scr_name, $cons_key, $cons_secret, $acce_token_key, $acce_token_secret  ) {
            $settings = array(
                'oauth_access_token' => $acce_token_key,
                'oauth_access_token_secret' => $acce_token_secret,
                'consumer_key' => $cons_key,
                'consumer_secret' => $cons_secret
            );
            $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json';
            $getfield = '?screen_name='.$scr_name;
            $requestMethod = 'GET';
            $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
            echo $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
             ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
             ->performRequest();

            // $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
            // return $twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
            //      ->setPostfields($postfields)
            //      ->performRequest();
        }
   $connection = get_Connection_With_Twitter_API( $instance['twitter_username'], $instance['twitter_consumerkey'], $instance['twitter_consumersecret'], $instance['twitter_accesstoken'], $instance['twitter_accesstokensecret'] );
```

I am getting this message:

```
{"errors":[{"code":89,"message":"Invalid or expired token."}]}
```

What I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure the tokens are current and valid? The error seems pretty clear that the API thinks they are not.

Comment: @AndyPiper can you tell me which API should I prefer to use?

Comment: What you're doing looks reasonable (although I've not tested the implementation with j7mbo's PHP library) but the error is indicating you need to have a valid API token.

Comment: @AndyPiper means instant of using this API `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json` I have to use other API

Comment: No, I meant that you should check that you have valid values for $instance['twitter_consumerkey'], $instance['twitter_consumersecret'], $instance['twitter_accesstoken'], $instance['twitter_accesstokensecret'].

Comment: @AndyPiper Yes I have checked them and they are valid

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me with my own API tokens and outputs the expected JSON response containing an array of followers. Either you have an issue with the tokens you are using, or the timestamp on your machine is out of sync (OAuth has a time component).

Comment: @AndyPiper I have changed the tokens also

Comment: @AndyPiper wait for a second, did you say your own API can you share your code. If you do not have any problem

Comment: I said my own tokens, which are associated with my Twitter account, so no I cannot share. I used the exact same code you posted here. The only way I can reproduce an error code 89 is if I put an invalid value into $acce_token_key - make sure you are putting the ACCESS TOKEN into the correct parameter to get_Connection_With_Twitter_API (maybe you mixed up consumer key and access token?)

Comment: @AndyPiper Sorry I have not aked for your access token I have just asked for the API link, have you used the same json link this -> `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json` or not. Sorry once again.

Comment: Yes I used the identical code you posted but I put my own values in the call to get_Connection - that API endpoint is correct.

Comment: @AndyPiper well thank for your assets. I will check my code again later.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have your access tokens and you are being careful not displaying them here, and you have created a new app on the twitter account. On that light, I strongly suggest you change the permission of your app to "Read, Write and Direct Message".
For the perfect and most simple and well documented api, I suggest Twit.